# MVC append nodes to xml file with jquery/c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an xml file with structure like this:

```
<ArrayOfUser
<User>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
</User>
</ArrayOfUser
```

I am attempting to grab information from a form and with it append to the xml file.

In my home controller I have this code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string writeMe()
        {
            string xmlFilePath = @"~App_Data/users.xml";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
            XmlElement foo = doc.CreateElement("User");
            XmlElement bar = doc.CreateElement("FirstName");
            bar.InnerText = "Test";
            foo.AppendChild(bar);
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(foo);
            doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
            return null;
        }
```

My JS code is this (not currently passing anything for testing purposes):

```
var FirstName = $("input[name='FirstName']").val();

     $.post("/Home/writeMe",
                {},
                function (response) {
                    alert("test");
                }
            );
```

I get the following error: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~App_Data\users.xml'.'"

I have tried other paths such as ...App_Data\users.xml, etc to no avail. Besides this error I am not confident I am approaching this correctly as I am VERY new to using MVC and use to winforms. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `string xmlFilePath = @"~App_Data/users.xml";` should be `string xmlFilePath = @"~/App_Data/users.xml";`  It lacks a '/'.

Comment: Jose when I change it I now get System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\App_Data\users.xml'.'

Comment: Oh, ok:  `doc.Load(Server.MapPath(xmlFilePath))`.  The same in the `save`

Comment: Thank you Jose! that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these two steps to fix your issue:

1. Put users.xml into App_Data-folder in your Visual Studio web project.
2. Get path App_Data-folder with this `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");`